# Compute $\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(2+t,3+t)-f(2,3)}{t}$ using the partial derivatives of $f$

Tags: limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

How can I solve the question? I know that I need to work with the definition of the partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$.

$$f'_y(2,3)=-3,\quad f'_x(2,3)=2\\
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(2+t,3+t)-f(2,3)}{t}=?$$

How can I continue from

$$\lim _{t \to 0} \frac {f(2+t, 3+t) - f(2+t, 3) + f(2+t, 3) - f(2,3)} t = ?$$

Comment: Just from the existence of partial derivatives you cannot prove anything about your limit; you'll need to assume that $f$ is differentiable, and then use the definition of differentiability.

Comment: ok and hwo i continue from this point?

Comment: Don't bother about adding and subtracting $f(2+t,3)$, since you can't use the definition of partials directly anyway. Just apply the definition of differentiability to the original expression.

Answer (score 1):

Define,

$$g(t)=f(2+t,3+t)=f(x(t),y(t))$$

Then we want to find $g'(0)$. So first let's try to find $g'(t)$. Using the chain rule,

$$g'(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

But here we have $x(t)=2+t$ and $y(t)=3+t$ so we get,

$$=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

Hence,

$$g'(0)=f_x(t=0)+f_y(t=0)$$

At $t=0$ we have $x=2$ and $y=3$ so that we are computing partials at the point $(x,y)=(2,3)$.

$$g'(0)=2+(-3)=-1$$

And so the limit is $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You need the approximation
$$
 f(2+t,3+t) \approx f(2,3) + t\, f_{x}(2,3) + t\, f_{y}(2,3) = f(2,3) + t\,(-3) + t\,(2)
$$

The derivative then becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} 
\frac{f(2+t,3+t) - f(2,3)} {t} = 
\frac{-3t+2t} {t} = -1
$$